# Angular load url when using a router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Im using Angular 7 + router. For example, my home page is `localhost:4200`, one of my router's url is `localhost:4200/route` and I have an API end point at `localhost:4200/api/foo`.

I'm trying to let the browser load the api end point from both locations. If I put an anchor with href pointing to the API end point, both anchor link works perfectly. However, I need to do it programmatically and I have tried all of the following methods

```
window.open("localhost:4200/api/foo","_self")
window.location.replace('localhost:4200/api/foo');
window.location.href = 'localhost:4200/api/foo';
```

They all works on the home page but if I'm in the router page, doing so will get me to the home page.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

To be specific, I have a spring boot server with url patterns like /api/*. All other urls are handled by angular. I want the browser to load `localhost:4200/api/foo`, which is directly handled by a get request defined in the server

Demo:

My nav bar is a component and it stays the same regardless of the router.
The code behind that button click is below. Note that the first time I click it under some Angular routed url, it loads the home page, not `google.com`

```
onLogIn() {
    window.open('https://www.google.com',"_self");
}
```

Routing.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IndexComponent } from "./index/index.component";
import { MicroserviceComponent } from "./microservice/microservice.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: IndexComponent},
    { path: 'microservice/:id', component: MicroserviceComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Can you please expand your question, I don't fully understand. You want to use the angular router to navigate to `/api/foo`?

Comment: This is a server-side issue. If you want to mix HTML and API routes on the same domain, then you'll need to look at Angular Universal and how you would add custom Express routes for APIs.

Comment: @JamieRees Updated my question

Comment: @cgTag This does not look like a server side issue. I put a break point in the server and it's not hit since it loads the main page

Comment: can you sow your routing.ts file

Comment: @FatehMohamed updated my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add pathMatch to your empty route, it's missing tht's why you're redirected to the home component

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: IndexComponent, pathMatch:'full'},
 { path: 'microservice/:id', component: MicroserviceComponent}
];
```